# Database sharding ( each user has their own database)

Tags: sharding

I have an application where a user gets there own database which is looked up based on the subdomain they are on. Currently I have over 100 users and it works fine. I have 1 web and 1 database server.

I imagine I can scale up probably to 500-1000 users without any changes.

For the web servers I can add a load balancer pretty easily so that shouldn't be an issue.

I am read when you shard databases you cannot have a lookup database as that defeats the purpose.

What is the best method to do this?

It seems like it would be pretty hard to manage as I keep adding shards as I would have to rebalance the servers.

What is a good approach to make this manageable?

Comment: Forgive my ignorance on this- but aren't you taking a significant performance hit from having 100+ databases on both the web and database servers, but needing to have unique connections/processes for each one?  Also, have you looked into a connection proxy -- ie a loadbalancer+connection-pool for your sql queries ?

Comment: Also, this doesn't sound like sharding.  This sounds like multiple databases.

Comment: There are multiple databases but they are only on one server. Each user has their own database

Comment: That's not sharding.  Sharding is storing sections of a single database ( ie, the tables ) on different database servers; ie partitioning within a database.  You don't need that.  You can just add entirely new database servers in your example.

Comment: Ah ok, I guess I misinterpreted the meaning

Answer (score 1):

If the user name is unique, and the naming convention compatible with database naming conventions, the database can use the same name as the user.

Or if the user is connecting through a website, part of the URL can be used. For example:

http://bobscarshop.wordpress.org/ could point to the database `bobscarshop`

Or, if you want a way to look up the server and database in one go, a technology like memcached or redis could be used to do this. They're distributed memory object caching systems that allow you to keep name/value pairs is a very scalable way.

Use http://bobscarshop.wordpress.org/ as your name and it could return you a big blob of data with whatever you need in it.

Comment: I don't think I made my question clear. If I have 10,000 users each with their own database, storing all these databases on one server will be problematic.

Comment: I already have the logic for pointing to the right database.

Comment: So you're after a way to determine the server without doing a lookup in a database?

Comment: Ok, added another option above :)

Answer (score 1):

You're not sharding.  You're just using multiple databases.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shard_(database_architecture)

> A database shard is a horizontal partition in a database or search
>   engine. Each individual partition is referred to as a shard or
>   database shard.

The easiest way to solve your problem is this:

- Add new database servers as needed , and reallocate databases to different servers based on needs ( ie, don't keep all the heavy users on the same system )
- Have some sort of centralized service that maps a user / application to a particular database.

For the centralized service, it might be best to manage this via it's own centralized Database instance.  As you scale out, you can introduce some sort of caching layer for lookups of this information (ie, webservers ask memcached first) or periodically publish a flatfile lookup to each machine in your cluster.

You could do use some sort of dispatch based on names, but then you can't easily migrate databases from one physical machine to another.

There are also load balancers/connection poolers for various databases that handle a lot of this.

Answer (score 0):

You could base the shards on first character of the subdomain, and decide which server to use in code based on that subdomain. For example (in pseudo-code):

```
if $username.charAt(0) < 'N' 
   $server = "database-server-1"
else 
   $server = "database-server-2"
end
```

would place Clownland on database-server-1 and TastyTreat on database-server-2.

Adding a server later on will require moving databases between servers, but that shouldn't be too painful if you can schedule a maintenance window.

This has the advantage of not requiring a tracking database for matching databases to servers.